# Signals emitted by QMenubar checkboxes in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, checkbox

I have created a MainWindow in Qt Designer and I have given checkboxes to some of the items in its dropdowns. Clearly, I can catch a triggered-signal when an item in one of the dropdowns is clicked. But, please, can anyone tell me how I can test if the click has changed the state of the respective checkbox. Only clicking on the item obviously does not always result in such a change. Does the checkbox itself emit a checked/unchecked signal each time its state changes? How can i catch such signal in Python?

OK, I thought my crude code wouldn't be very helpful:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwidget = loadUi("main.ui")
mainwidget.show()
mainwidget.ACTION.triggered.connect(EVENTHANDLER_IF_CLICKED)
mainwidget.ACTION.stateChanged(int ???).connect(EVENTHANDLER_IF_CHECKED)
```

My idea is to somehow connect a signal emitted by ACTION, where ACTION represents a menubar item, to either of the eventhandlers. At present I plan to do this outside a class. It works with the "clicked"-event. But I don't how to do this with the checkbox.

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: OK, I thought my crude code wouldn't be very helpful:

Answer (score 0):

Try catching the **stateChanged(int state)** signal event

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems there is no such signal as I was looking for. Whatever you are doing to a checkbox in a menubar will emit the unsual triggered signal. However, the state of the checkbox appears to be an 'bool' attribute of the item in the menubar. Therefore, I found it helpful to rely on the triggered signal and, within the eventhandler it calls, test the attribute.
Thanks to anyone who tried to help.